# How do I add an unchanged file to git index

Tags: git, jgit

I am writing a tool that has to keep history of (generated) files in a Git repository.

One of the requests is that I must be able to take whatever was generated in a specific commit and replay those into another branch.

On the surface, it looks very much like a cherry-picking, but there are nuances that make this a little bit different.

Each commit generates a set of files into the working tree. Some files may already exist in the working tree, and quite often, the generated content is unchanged from the version in the working tree.

At some later time, I must be able to take the list of files that were generated for the previous commit (regardless whether the content was changed or not) and copy those to another branch.

My first question is: **Can I add a file to git index (and eventually commit) even if its content has not changed?**

If I will have to muck around with git internals for that, it is still okay. 
I just need to be sure that it will not to break the git repo for other git tools.

I am using Java and open source jGit library for interacting with Git repository, so my second question is, if this is possible in jGit

If yes, then some API pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your explicit question - if a file existed in your previous commit, and its content has not changed at all (although its metadata may have), then the file is already in the index. Immediately after a commit, the index contains the exact contents of that commit. Adding/deleting changes makes appropriate modifications to the index to prepare for the next commit. Counter to a couple other answers/comments, `git` does not store changes - it stores complete snapshots of your working directory (or at least the non-ignored, not-untracked parts of it). It *calculates* changes when you ask it to, but it does not store them (at least from the `git` front-end perspective - the underlying object database will use deltas to reduce the amount of space required, but the deltas it uses may not be between consecutive versions of a file, and may not even be between two versions of the same file if you have files that are significantly similar).

To answer what it sounds like you are wanting to do, you might want to research `git reset --merge`. If that's not quite what you want, you can do something like this, which will change the current working directory to match a specific commit, and then commit that state as a new commit - essentially copying the snapshot represented by the source commit, which is likely on a different branch or possibly earlier in the current branch, and making a new commit that looks just like it, except for what is considered to be the parent commit:

```
git rm -r *
git archive --format=tar <commit> | tar xpf -
git add -A .
git commit -m "snapshot copy of commit <commit>"
```

You could use `git archive --format=zip <commit> -o /tmp/somefile.zip; unzip /tmp/somefile.zip` as well, but I prefer to use the `tar` format since you can just pipe it...

Comment: Do you have a link that illustrates how git does not store changes but instead "snapshots" of the entire working tree only to convert that to deltas (changes)? Thanks.

Comment: Any of these three would be a good place to start: [1](http://git-scm.com/doc), [2](http://git-scm.com/book), [3](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/). There are many others out there, though, with a little Googling...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `git update-index` is dedicated to the manipulation of the index. You should find what you need in [its documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index).

Answer (score 1):

Git stores changes not files. You're better off using something more suited for file storage and time stamping (database) then version control.

To force the idea of doing what you want in git the only thing I can think of would be to have the generator add a build number or unique MD5 + seed(time.now) to the file so that git will see a change that it can then commit.

But again this really smells like the solution does not fit the problem. Are you absolutely sure using a version control system to record runs of a generator script is the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have to agree that `git` most probably is not the correct way to go.

The rest of this answer lays somewhere between experimentation and the ugly hack world.

What comes to mind is having in your repository a file that will have your files' structure inside eg `repo_files`.

You can then implement a hook to add the new files to the `repo_files`.

So at any point you'll have the ability to know the repo plus the empty files you need.

With these implemented you can write some custom git commands to do what you need

eg:

- `generate_repo_files` which populates the `repo_files` file
- `commit_empty_file` which will just add the file to `repo_files`
- `checkout_with_files` which will do a checkout and touch the missing files
- `remove_files` which will remove empty files from `repo_files`